# Using Same Variable in Multiple PHP `while` Loops

Tags: php, variables, scope

I have a PHP page with multiple `mysql_query` instances. Almost every one uses a `while` loop to retrieve multiple rows of data.

As I keep a snippet of this often used code, and the example I was taught with, used the variable `$row`, **I have multiple instances of the following on my page:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($foo_data)) { 
    $barArray[] = $row['barValue']; 
}
```

I even have  an instance of `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($foo_data)` *without* a `while` loop.

**I'm wondering if the multiple uses of `$row` as a variable on a single page, is all right?**

The PHP is functioning fine, but I always want to be sure that my code is proper and conforms to standard rules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is fine. but if you try:

```
var_dump($row);
```

at the end of your code -- it will only return that last value of `$row`

Comment: So what you're saying is, if I use `$row`, and it has been used before, then if overwrites its previous value(s) with a new one. And that this is ok because the value that is being overwritten, has already been used in whatever operation was contained within the previous `while` loop, etc. Does that sound about right? Maybe not eloquent...

Comment: the previous while loop is **over**. PHP runs in order.

Comment: Exactly. Wonderful. And much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

yes, it's all right.
it's all right to use the same spoon when you're eating soup.

Comment: But remember to lick all the soup off first.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, not a problem at all.

Just like always using `$i` as your count in a `for` loop, you can repeatedly use `$row` to no ill effect.